# How to restore values of spinners in a custom listview after adding new list item to the list

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, custom-adapter

**Overview:** I am working on a project named GPA calculator. Where user can add his subjects with grade and credit Hours for each subject and calculate GPA. I am using fragment for each semester GPA calculation.

I am using a custom listview for each subject details . Listview contains EditText(subject_name), Spinner(grade_earned), Spinner(Credit_hrs_of_subject) and Button(delete_current_row).

I am using a Button to add new row (subject,grade and credit_hours) to the custom listview.

Another Button to calculate the GPA.(getting values from custom listview items and calculating GPA ).

Till here my code is working perfectly and I am getting the desired results.

**Problem**: When I add one row to the listview and change the values of spinners(grade and credit hours) and then create another row , it refreshes the values of previous spinners to first item. **OR** by scrolling the list also removes the selected spinner item values and showing first item on all spinners.

**Thanks in Advance**
As I am working on this issue for the last three nights but failed to fix it..

My code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class OneFragment extends ListFragment {

    public ListView MyListView;
    public ArrayList<String> TitlesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    int count = 1;


    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Button btnAdd = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnAddSub1);
        Button btnCalculate= (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);

        MyListView=getListView();

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TitlesArray.add("Subject " + count++);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //get list items data
                List<String> GradeList = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> CreditsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < MyListView.getChildCount(); i++) {

                    // Get row's spinner
                    View listItem = MyListView.getChildAt(i);
                    Spinner grades = (Spinner) listItem.findViewById(R.id.spinnerGrades);

                    Spinner CrdHrs = (Spinner) listItem.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCrdHrs);

                    // Get selection
                    String grade = (String) grades.getSelectedItem();
                    String CreditHrs = (String) CrdHrs.getSelectedItem();
                    GradeList.add(grade);
                    CreditsList.add(CreditHrs);
                }

                //calculating gpa--formula work--working fine
                String[] gradeArray = GradeList.toArray(new String[0]);
                String[] CreditsArray = CreditsList.toArray(new String[0]);
                double addedvals=0;
                double addCreditsTotol=0;
                for(int i=0; i<MyListView.getChildCount();i++){
                double valxOfgrade= Double.parseDouble(MainActivity.getValueOfGrade(getActivity(),gradeArray[i]));
                double valxOfcredits= Double.parseDouble(CreditsArray[i]);
                    double multiply=valxOfcredits*valxOfgrade;
                    addedvals+=multiply;
                    addCreditsTotol+=Double.parseDouble(CreditsArray[i]);

                }

                double GPAval=addedvals/addCreditsTotol;

                TextView TVgpa = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.TVGPA);
                TVgpa.setText("Your gpa is : "+String.valueOf(GPAval));



            }
        });

        adapter = new MynewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_view_semester, TitlesArray);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public class MynewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public int layout;
        public MynewAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            layout = resource;
        }
        boolean delete;
        Context mContext;

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
            final int pos=position;
            ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;
            mContext = parent.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
          convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.title = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ETsubject);
            viewHolder.grade = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerGrades);
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MainActivity.Grades);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            viewHolder.grade.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            viewHolder.credits = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCrdHrs);
            viewHolder.btnDelete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

            viewHolder.grade.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String str=(String)    parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Log.d("values str",String.valueOf(str));
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });


//delete button
        viewHolder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                delete=true;
              TitlesArray.remove(position);
                Log.d("focus","delete");

               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            mainViewHolder.title.setText(getItem(position));

            viewHolder.title.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
/*
 * When focus is lost save the entered value of editText
 */
                            if (!hasFocus) {

                                if(delete==true){
                                    delete=false;
                                }else{
                                String enteredTitle = ((EditText) v).getText().toString();
                               TitlesArray.set(pos, enteredTitle);

                            }
                        }

                        }
                    });


            return convertView;
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            EditText title;
            Spinner grade;
            Spinner credits;
            ImageButton btnDelete;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you storing the values for the selected item you have for the spinners? You're reusing views, but you're never storing the values. Once you notify the data set is changed, it reloads all the items, and you'll lose all of your spinner values. You have to store these somewhere.

Comment: Create a data structure (a Row class) that has all the values for a row in your adapter. Then set all of the values for that row as they are updated. Your ArrayAdapter Class should be created like new ArrayAdapter<Row> and the data object in your adapter should be a Row object. This way you can store all of the information you need in one Class.

Comment: @Shadesblade Sir i tried that approach as well. and i was successfully storing the values in arraylist with row index of each spinner. But i don't know how to retrieve those old values which are stored in arraylist. how  and where i would write the retrieve code...

Comment: Please write down an example code of what you are saying... @Shdesblade

Answer (score 0):

At last after a long search i found the solution of my problem. here is the link of the answer I followed [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20855933/6105390)

My updated code :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class OneFragment extends ListFragment {

    public ListView MyListView;
    public ArrayList<String> TitlesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    int count = 1;

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Button btnAdd = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnAddSub1);
        Button btnCalculate= (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
        final EditText etSubs= (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.ETnoOfSubs);

        MyListView=getListView();

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            int subs= Integer.parseInt(etSubs.getText().toString());

               for(int i=0;i<subs;i++) {
                   TitlesArray.add("Subject " + count++);
               }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //get list items data
                List<String> GradeList = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> CreditsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < MyListView.getChildCount(); i++) {

                    // Get row's spinner
                    View listItem = MyListView.getChildAt(i);
                    Spinner grades = (Spinner) listItem.findViewById(R.id.spinnerGrades);

                    Spinner CrdHrs = (Spinner) listItem.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCrdHrs);

                    // Get selection
                    String grade = (String) grades.getSelectedItem();
                    String CreditHrs = (String) CrdHrs.getSelectedItem();
                    GradeList.add(grade);
                    CreditsList.add(CreditHrs);
                }

                //calculating gpa--formula work--working fine
                String[] gradeArray = GradeList.toArray(new String[0]);
                String[] CreditsArray = CreditsList.toArray(new String[0]);
                double addedvals=0;
                double addCreditsTotol=0;
                for(int i=0; i<MyListView.getChildCount();i++){
                double valxOfgrade= Double.parseDouble(MainActivity.getValueOfGrade(getActivity(),gradeArray[i]));
                double valxOfcredits= Double.parseDouble(CreditsArray[i]);
                    double multiply=valxOfcredits*valxOfgrade;
                    addedvals+=multiply;
                    addCreditsTotol+=Double.parseDouble(CreditsArray[i]);

                }

                double GPAval=addedvals/addCreditsTotol;

                TextView TVgpa = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.TVGPA);
                TVgpa.setText("Your gpa is : "+String.valueOf(GPAval));
            }
        });

        adapter = new MynewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_view_semester, TitlesArray);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public class MynewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public int layout;
        public MynewAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            layout = resource;
        }
        boolean delete;

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            View v = convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if(v == null){

                v=inflater.inflate(layout, parent,false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.title = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.ETsubject);
                viewHolder.grade = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerGrades);
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MainActivity.Grades);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                viewHolder.grade.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                viewHolder.credits = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCrdHrs);
                viewHolder.btnDelete = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
                v.setTag(viewHolder);
            }else{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }
            String s = getItem(position);
            viewHolder.title.setText(s);


            viewHolder.grade.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String str=(String)    parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Log.d("values str",String.valueOf(str));
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });


//delete button
        viewHolder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                delete=true;
              TitlesArray.remove(position);
                Log.d("focus","delete");

               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });


            viewHolder.title.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
/*
 * When focus is lost save the entered value of editText
 */
                            if (!hasFocus) {

                                if(delete==true){
                                    delete=false;
                                }else{
                                String enteredTitle = ((EditText) v).getText().toString();
                               TitlesArray.set(position, enteredTitle);
                            }
                            }

                        }
                    });


            return v;
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            EditText title;
            Spinner grade;
            Spinner credits;
            ImageButton btnDelete;
        }
    }

}
```